# Flex Bison Reading from file get segmentation fault if file does not exist

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I have flex code that can parse the contents of a file, but if the file that is trying to be read does not exist, I get a segmentation fault.

The flex file does interface with bison as well but this part of the code does not, let me know if you would like the bison file anyways.

flex code:

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "helper.h"
#include "spire.tab.h"
void yyerror(char *);
%}

%x incl
%%
include BEGIN(incl);

...

\"[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+\.(spr)\" {
        char *f = strdup(yytext);

        f++[strlen(f)-1] = 0;

        yyin = fopen( f, "r" );

        if (! yyin)
                printf("Could not read %s\n", f);
        yypush_buffer_state(yy_create_buffer( yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE ));

        BEGIN(INITIAL);
}

<<EOF>> {
        yypop_buffer_state();

        if ( !YY_CURRENT_BUFFER )
        {
                yyterminate();
        }
}


[ \t\n]+ ; /* ignore whitespace */
. yyerror("Unknown character");


%%

int yywrap(void) {
 return 1;
}
```

if the file does not exist I get this for output (for file fle.spr)

```
Could not read fle.spr
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

EDIT:

Changed

```
 if (! yyin)
     printf("Could not read %s\n", f);
 yypush_buffer_state(yy_create_buffer( yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE ));
```

to

```
if (! yyin){
    printf("Could not read %s\n", f);
}else{
    yypush_buffer_state(yy_create_buffer( yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE ));
}
```

Still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that is surprising.

Your code checks to see if the file open worked. If not, it prints an error message (on `stdout` rather than `stderr`, but that's a minor detail) *and then continues*.

Immediately afterwards, the scanner will attempt to read from `yyin`, but `yyin` is NULL. So it segfaults, as expected.

If a file doesn't exist, *don't try reading it*. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Changed it to  `if (! yyin){
                printf("Could not read %s\n", f);
        }else{
                yypush_buffer_state(yy_create_buffer( yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE ));
        }` Still getting the same error

Comment: @joshYoung: yes, because *you still continue the parse with yyin set to NULL.* You need to not destroy the value of `yyin`.  Use a temporary variable, and call `yy_create_buffer` with that variable.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, I am very new to C, and Flex, That worked.

Comment: @JoshYoung: Yeah, I understand. But it's got to be said that it is easier to learn flex/bison if you already know at least the basics of C programming.